# Wmi Failed to parse wdg method error every time when i turn on

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, 22.04, execute-command

I use a Dell Vostro and I was able to install Ubuntu 20.04/22.04 successfully. I did

```
sudo apt update 
apt upgrade
```

and restarted the OS, but I am getting this error

```
wmi failed to parse wdg method.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Upgrade is recommended. If your system starts as it should, this might be just an information message. Which kernel version are you using? BIOS upgrade available? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/WMI

Comment: What version were you intending to install: 20.04, 21.04, or 22.04? You wrote 21.04 but tagged with the other 2.